# MongoDB Aggregation - $project with $cond

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use MongoDBs (v.3.2.11) aggregation framework to process some log documents that look like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b753c6d4421f00216de942"), 
    "session_id" : "7CB8725A-3994-45B8-9CA2-92FC19406288", 
    "event_type" : "connect_begin", 
    "timestamp" : "1488409541.674997", 
    "user_id" : "f6830aac-60be-44df-9fa7-7aa530d637ce", 
    "u_at" : ISODate("2017-03-01T23:05:42.077Z"), 
    "c_at" : ISODate("2017-03-01T23:05:42.077Z") 
}
```

My collection contains pairs of the above logs that share a `session_id`, one log for the `begin` event and one for the `end` event. The end goal is to calculate the length of these sessions via the difference in the timestamps.

So far I have been able to write an aggregation pipeline that groups the logs by `$session_id` and provides an array of the two `$events` associated with the session. My idea was that next I would `$project` the begin and end timestamps onto the final result using a `$cond` to check the `event_type` of each `$event` in the array, which will tell me if it is a `begin` or `end` event. I have pasted what I have so far below:

```
db.time_spent_logs.aggregate([
    { $group: {
            _id: '$session_id',
            events: {
                $push: {
                    event_type: '$event_type', 
                    timestamp: '$timestamp'
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { $project: {
        start: {
            $cond: { 
                if: { $or: [ { $strcasecmp: [ "$events[0].event_type", "trending_begin" ]}, { $strcasecmp: [ "$events[0].event_type", "connect_begin" ]}] },
                then: '$events[0].timestamp', 
                else: '$events[1].timestamp'
            }
        },
        end: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $or: [ { $strcasecmp: [ "$events[0].event_type", "trending_end" ]}, { $strcasecmp: [ "$events[0].event_type", "connect_end" ]}] },
                then: '$events[0].timestamp', 
                else: '$events[1].timestamp'

            }
        }
    }}
])
```

This produces a list of the following:

```
{ "_id" : "4EC4B831-D3C7-49C6-9EC8-301981639ED7" }
```

I think my problem is in the `if` of my `$cond`, where I am comparing the value of the `event_type` field for each `$event` with a string to see if it is one of our two `begin` or `end` event types. I believe it is somewhere in this `$if $or $strcasecompare` where I have something wrong...

I have attempted using `$literal` to compare the `event_type` as well to no result.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can not use the square bracket `[]` operator to index array element. That being said can you tell us the `mongod` version your are running? What is the expected output of your query?

Comment: @styvane - version 3.2.11, I have updated the question. I didn't realize you couldn't use bracket notation- Thank you for the information!

Comment: @laurynloudermilk Do you just have one event type pair tied to unique session ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MongoDB v 3.2 and above you could use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead of applying the conditions manually like this:

```js
{
 $project: {
  start: {
   //Filter the events, keep only 'begin' events
   $filter: {
    input: '$events',
    as: 'event',
    cond: {$in: ['$$event.event_type', ['trending_begin', 'connect_begin']]}
   }
  },
  end: {
   //Same with 'end' events
   $filter: {
    input: '$events',
    as: 'event',
    cond: {$in: ['$$event.event_type', ['trending_end', 'connect_end']]}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So the resulting 'start' and 'end' properties will be arrays of start and end events respectively.
If you're sure that the data is consistent and you have exactly 2 event (start and end) records matching the session then you can safely use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to take the first element of the array:

```js
{
 $project: {
  start: {
   //Take first of the filtered events
   $arrayElemAt: [{
    $filter: {
     input: '$events',
     as: 'event',
     cond: {$in: ['$$event.event_type', ['trending_begin', 'connect_begin']]}
    }
   }, 0]
  },
  end: {
   //Take first of the filtered events
   $arrayElemAt: [{
    $filter: {
     input: '$events',
     as: 'event',
     cond: {$in: ['$$event.event_type', ['trending_end', 'connect_end']]}
    }
   }, 0]
  }
 }
}
```

And you'll have 'start' and 'end' as plain objects.
Here is the [whole query](http://jsbin.com/memeluteki/1/edit?js).

Comment: @laurynloudermilk Hey! hm... The problem might be caused by MongoDB version. The $arrayElemAt was added in v 3.2. Which version are you at?

Comment: Antonio - I thought i was running v3.2.11 but it turns out that's my shell version and not my db version. I've opened a ticket to have my mongodb upgraded and will update here if your solution works after upgrade.

Comment: IT WORKS!! I had to substitute `$in` for `$setIsSubset` because we could only upgrade to 3.2, and `$in` is new to 3.4. Once i changed that your pipeline worked flawlessly. Thank you SO MUCH!